# Unit tests failing: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have started to get this error only on my local for some unit tests which were fine before, build runs fine not sure why though!

Not sure where to set jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL?

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

```
xit('id should be set for time', () => {
expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(' #form-details-offDutyTime')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Your test is ignored by `xit`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Default jasmine time  interval is 5sec.

You could increase the jasmine `default timeout interval` by passing the time as a parameter to `it` block.

```
it('id should be set for time', () => {
expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(' #form-details-offDutyTime')).toBeTruthy();
}, 10000);
```